Add "contains"/"overlap" checks in the ask-wizard to prevent duplicate content
With the implementation of Can you prevent users from using same content in ask question wizard? last year it is not possible to add the same content in the two textareas on the Ask Wizard. You get the following error message when you try to do so:

Problem details and expected results must be different.

As mentioned in a comment by MisterMiyagi, it was anticipated that users might pad the messages they enter in both input fields. That is exactly what is happening sometimes. There are questions where the content is copied into the other textarea, but then added by some harmless dummy/filler text (or worst, but some nonsense) to bypass this check. This makes this check less effective as it does not trigger a change in the users behavior to actually not copy the content from the first textarea into the second area (at least in those such questions we see, check survivorship bias). Instead they should write different content according to the Ask Wizard ("What are the details of your problem?" and "What did you try and what were you expecting?"). I guess, the (short) error message sounds similar to a "password requirement check" where you need to add numbers to your password (so you add a 1 at the end, who cares...). The user simply add the filler text to bypass the check as quick as possible.
The check for duplicate content should be improved that not a simple "exact equals" check is used but also a "contains" (or "overlap") check is added. When one textarea content is contained in the other textarea content in any way, then the content was clearly copied. Such duplicate content will not provide any new information for the question.
The error message should also be more detailed. It should indicate what the problem is and what the user should do (instead of trying to bypass it). Maybe rephrase it like this:

Please do not add the same content in the two input fields. Both content will be displayed on the resulting question page, without providing any new information. Instead provide details about the problem in the first input field and the current result and expected result in the second input field.

The wording might be tricky since the same error message is shown on both input fields, even thought it will most likely be triggered by the second input field.
